# How to get the TextView Tag from a TextView inside of a ListView

Tags: android, listview, textview

I am currently working on android project where I am using a custom list view which TextViews for each item. I am settings the displayable text by using `myTextView.setText("my text")` and then setting the TextView tag by using `myTextView.setTag("my tag")`.

Once its in the list view I then want to allow the user to click on the item within the list view and retrieve the textview text as well as the tag.

I've tried `TextView textView = (TextView)getListAdapter().getItem(position);`
and ``TextView textView = (TextView)getListView().getItem(position); but it keeps saying that it can't can't from String to TextView.

How can I get the tag and the text from the text view.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

**UPDATE 1**
As requested this is a ListActivity that I am using and below is the code for the item click event

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    //get selected items
    //String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    //TextView textView = (TextView)appArrayAdapter.getItem(position);
    TextView textView = (TextView)getListView().getChildAt(position);
    String selectedValue = textView.getText().toString();
    String selectedPackage = textView.getTag().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("appName", selectedValue);
    intent.putExtra("packageName", selectedPackage );
    setResult(0, intent);
    finish();
}
```

And the below code is the code that sets the list adapter

```
final ArrayList<ResolveInfo> list = (ArrayList<ResolveInfo>)pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        imageList = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
        packageName = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i != list.size(); i++)
        {
            String text = list.get(i).activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
            String appPackage = list.get(i).activityInfo.packageName;
            arrayList.add(text);
            Drawable imageId = list.get(i).activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);
            packageName.add(appPackage);
            imageList.add(imageId);
        }

        appArrayAdapter = new AppArrayAdapter(this, arrayList);
        //setListAdapter(new AppArrayAdapter(this, arrayList));
        setListAdapter(appArrayAdapter);

    }
```

And the below code is the appArrayExtender class

```
public class AppArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
    {
        private final Context context;
        private final ArrayList<String> arrayList;
        //private final ArrayList<Drawable> imageList;

        public AppArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arrayList/*, ArrayList<Drawable> imageList*/)
        {
            super(context, R.layout.select_apps, arrayList);
            this.context = context;
            this.arrayList = arrayList;
            //this.imageList = imageList;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.select_apps, parent, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);

            textView.setText(arrayList.get(position));
            textView.setTag(packageName.get(position));
            imageView.setImageDrawable(imageList.get(position));
            //imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
            return rowView;
        }
    }
```

And below is the XML for the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="50px"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
        android:layout_marginRight="20px"
        android:layout_marginTop="5px" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label" >
    </TextView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code. What you have provided doesn't have much context, is this a ListActivity? Are you using an OnItemClickListener?

Comment: That should work fine, where is the problem? Bear in mind that View v in the arguments of onListItemClick is the View pressed, meaning you could instead use `TextView textview = (TextView) v`;

Comment: Its saying that it can't cant to type TextView. I've tried using the way you suggested using ``(TextView)v;`` but I then get the following exception: ``java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView``. I've also posted the XML layout in case it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the text *from* the TextView, use the information passed into the `onClick` rather than all that extra code.  The framework passes in the view that was clicked on (the View v parameter).  If it is a single TextView, you can do `v.getText().toString()`, if it is a more complex layout, you can use `v.findViewById(R.id.TextView1)` to get the proper TextView and the use `getText().toString()` on it:

```
@Override 
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) { 

    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.yourRowLayoutWidget);  // get the widget contained in the layout
    String selectedValue = textView.getText().toString(); // get the value of the widget into a string
    // do what you will with the string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when the list view is scrolled, view items, that just disappeared are passed to the getView of adapters method as an argument convertView, so u set Tag f.e. on 7 item and than it is converted to the 1st cause 7th is no longer wisivle and the 1st item will have the wrong tag;

I suggest u to extends BaseAdapter and store some object with all the data u need.

it would look like this

```
public class DialogsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private List<YourObjectToStoreData> mData ;

    public DialogsAdapter(Context context, List<YourObjectToStoreData> data
    ) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        mData = data;
    }
    ...
```

also take a look at [Holder Pattern](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html) it might be usefull